# Fastest way to compute C = A x B x A

Tags: matrix, matrix-multiplication, intel-mkl

What is the fastest way to compute C = A x B x A using Intel MKL?

A, B, C are all (n x n) matrices.

At the moment I'm using twice `cblas_dgemm`, see https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl-developer-reference-c-cblas-gemm.

See the following pseudo code:

```
C = dgemm(dgemm(A, B), A)
```

Is there a faster way to compute it?

**EDIT**

It could happen as well that I've multiple matrices `B[i]` and I want to compute multiple matrices `C[i]` with the same matrix `A`, see the following pseudo code:

```
for i = 1:m
    C[i] = dgemm(dgemm(A, B[i]), A)
end
```

It would be very nice I've could speed up this calculation :-)

Comment: Any special properties about either of those matrices?  Symmetric, orthogonal, etc?  Are either of them reused for more than a single iteration?

Comment: The only thing which is special that there is twice `A` in the function. On the left and on the right of `B`. And yes there will be different `B[i]` and `A` will stay constant. I'll edit the question.

Comment: Is there anything special about the structure of `A`, or of each `B[i]`? I am in similar situation with a diagonal `B[i]` and the calculation `C=transpose(A)*B[i]*A`

Comment: Also, what is the `n` typically, and have you looked at [**`Strassen`**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strassen_algorithm) type algorithms?

Comment: In my case n is between 10 and 1000. And m could be between 1 and 10000. And I hope that `Strassen` is implement in Intel MKL cblas_dgemm.

Comment: If the next matrix B is only slightly different from the previous one, the update of product matrix C would be A(Bnew - Bold)A where the difference matrix could be sparse and thus more efficient to multiply.

Comment: `cblas_dgemm_batch` would be an option to speed it up, see https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl-developer-reference-c-cblas-gemm-batch and https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/introducing-batch-gemm-operations. But I'm not able to call it from C#, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46192663/c-sharp-calling-intel-mkl-cblas-dgemm-batch.